# How 'Following' works in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I have a cloud firestore collection of users, all with the name, username, email, password and follower fields and basically what i am trying to do in this app is create a follow button and an unfollow button. When the follow is clicked, i want the followers field of that particular user to be updated with the 'username' of the current user and when i click the unfollow button, i want the username to be removed.How do i go about doing this? P.S Adding the username of the current user to the followed users follower field is just how i thought it would make sense so if there are better way to solving this, i am absolutely open to them

Answer (score 0):

from my opinion

- > you may need to create a list/array of followers and every time user
  > hits follow button it adds this user to this list

or

- > you can do junction table put simply you will need to create a collection named USERID_FOLLOWERS and every time user hits its just
  > add or remove specific document and this is better to deal with big
  > data